# Ionic Angular - Android platform with reCaptcha use

Tags: android, angular, ionic3, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate reCaptcha with my Ionic Android/IOS app. The reason for this is that it calls the same API as the public Web app API.

I have tried creating a web key but due to the fact that the app is served from file:// it doesn't have a domain and as such i cant white list it.

I also tried to create a Android key and white list the App's package name but in both cases, i get the same error: 
"error for site owner invalid domain for site key"

I tried using these recaptcha angular wrappers: ng-recaptcha and angular2-recaptcha, but obviously they fail as is a domain issue.

Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: Check this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116411/recaptcha-ionic-cordova-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

So, after long searches and reading everything i found on the subject, i managed to find a workaround. 
Instead of trying to load the captcha in my Ionic app, i am using the in-app-browser to open a page on our web version of the app that has the captcha. When the captcha is checked, it saves the code in the localStorage of the in-app-browser.

When the browser is initially opened i start running a script on the browser that checks its storage for the captchaCode.

Code example:

```
captchaCheck($event){

        const browser = this.iab.create(YOUR_CAPTCHA_PAGE_URL_HERE,'_blank', 'location=no'); //AppSettings.CAPTCHA_URL
        let loginCtx = this;
        browser.on( "loadstop").subscribe(function() {
            browser.executeScript({ code: "localStorage.setItem( 'captchaCode', '' );" });
            var loop = setInterval(function() {
                browser.executeScript({code: "localStorage.getItem( 'captchaCode' )"}).then((values)=>{
                    var captchaCode = values[0];
                    if (captchaCode) {
                        loginCtx.signinForm.get('captchaCode').setValue(captchaCode);
                        clearInterval( loop );
                        browser.close();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }

}
```