# how can I install correctly ngx-recaptcha on my project?

Tags: html, typescript, angular6, recaptcha

I'm doing a form to register an Ad, but when I installed the recaptcha it doesn't works Ok, I couldn't reset it or reload it, etc, I've followed the tutorial to the letter and nothing, this is the page, meanly [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-captcha)

```html
<ngx-recaptcha2 #captchaElem
  [siteKey]="siteKey"
  (reset)="handleReset()"
  (expire)="handleExpire()"
  (load)="handleLoad()"
  (success)="handleSuccess($event)"
  [useGlobalDomain]="false"
  [size]="size"
  [hl]="lang"
  [theme]="theme"
  [type]="type"
  formControlName="recaptcha">
</ngx-recaptcha2>
```

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgxCaptchaModule } from 'ngx-captcha';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreateadsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgxCaptchaModule,
    ......
```

```js
this.aFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      recaptcha: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

it throws this error:

ERROR in ../node_modules/ngx-captcha/lib/components/base-recaptcha.component.d.ts(13,44): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
../node_modules/ngx-captcha/lib/components/invisible-recaptcha.component.d.ts(13,31): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
../node_modules/ngx-captcha/lib/components/recaptcha-2.component.d.ts(13,56): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

and nothing works fine later, just show correct tag in the page, but I can't do anything with it, no reset, no validate... 
Somebody can help me please.

Comment: Getting the same issue with the latest version: "ngx-captcha": "^7.0.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same error, but using reCaptcha v3.

The solution was to downgrade the package to version 5.0.4.

`npm install ngx-captcha@5.0.4`

**[ReCaptcha V3]**

When downgrading, the method `execute` has fewer parameters.
`this.reCaptchaV3Service.execute(this.siteKey, 'homepage', (token) => {
    console.log('This is your token: ', token);
 });`

**[Removing ReCaptcha V3 Badge]**

On `index.html` add:

`<style>
   .grecaptcha-badge { visibility: collapse !important; }
 </style>`